# PyQt5 UI stuck at long operation

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm creating a game with some AI that may take some time. The problem is even if I call relevant methods to update the UI before running the AI function, the UI is not visually updated.

Some example code looks like this

```
    def onClickBoard(self, e):
        x, y = toBoardGrid(e.x(), e.y())
        self.game.move(x, y)
        self.update_board()

        print("before AI")
        # This line takes a few seconds
        ai_move = self.ai.get_best_move(self.game)
        print("after AI")
        self.game.move(ai_move[0], ai_move[1])
        self.update_board()
```

Where `self.update_board` is a method that updates a QWidget and it's very fast. This `onClickBoard` method is assigned to the widget's `mouseReleaseEvent`.

```
    self.board.mouseReleaseEvent = self.onClickBoard
```

When running the game, I can see `before AI` printed to the terminal but the visual window doesn't change. I see the window updates only once, after the AI commits its move.

Is there a way to make the board update once before the slow function call and another once after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can force Qt to process all pending events, and thus update the GUI, with the [QApplication::processEvents()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) method. Add the following line just before the slow function call:

```
QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().processEvents()
```

Comment: @eyllanesc: not sure what you mean with the link can you elaborate?

Comment: I disagree. Yes, the GUI will block during the long function call, but if it's only a few seconds this may be acceptable (if it's 10 seconds it's probably not, but that's up to @iBug). Threading is indeed a more scalable solution but requires a lot more work and debugging. In fact the [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/thread-basics.html#when-to-use-alternatives-to-threads) warns about this and suggests `processEvents` as an alternative to threads. @iBug literally asked if the UI could be updated before the slow function call and I gave the answer. No need for downvotes IMO.

Comment: A surprisingly easy solution.